# Force only enum values, but ensure the string name is passed

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

Assuming I have these enum and interface:

```typescript
export enum IFundingMethods = {
   ONLINE_DEBIT,
   BOLETO,
   CREDIT_CARD
}

export interface IFunding {
   method: IFundingMethods;
   /* ... */
}

function send(opts: IFunding) { /*...*/ }
```

When calling the function `send`, the compiler will ask for either IFundMethods.ONLINE_DEBIT, BOLETO or CREDIT_CARD. So when calling the function with:

```typescript
send({method: IFundMethods.ONLINE_DEBIT});
```

the function receives a `{method: 0}`, how can I make it transform to `ONLINE_DEBIT` string without having to typecast it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this being used.

```
 enum IFundingMethods {
    ONLINE_DEBIT =<any>'ONLINE_DEBIT',
    BOLETO =<any>'BOLETO',
    CREDIT_CARD =<any>'CREDIT_CARD'
}
```

Typescript compiles it to this:

```
var IFundingMethods;
(function (IFundingMethods) {
    IFundingMethods[IFundingMethods["ONLINE_DEBIT"] = 'ONLINE_DEBIT'] = "ONLINE_DEBIT";
    IFundingMethods[IFundingMethods["BOLETO"] = 'BOLETO'] = "BOLETO";
    IFundingMethods[IFundingMethods["CREDIT_CARD"] = 'CREDIT_CARD'] = "CREDIT_CARD";
})(IFundingMethods || (IFundingMethods = {}));
```

It's not the nicest code but creates an enum that uses strings as values. This should achieve what you're trying to accomplish for the time being. Once typescript allows for a more direct way of creating a string-enum you can change to that.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum), you can get the string value of an Enum by referencing the Enum as an array with its index.

```
enum IFundingMethods {
   ONLINE_DEBIT,
   BOLETO,
   CREDIT_CARD
}
class EnumHelper{
    help(base:IFundingMethods)  {
        return IFundingMethods[base]
    }
}
var test :EnumHelper = new EnumHelper();
alert(test.help(IFundingMethods.CREDIT_CARD));
```

more generic solution

```
enum IFundingMethods {
   ONLINE_DEBIT,
   BOLETO,
   CREDIT_CARD
}
class Util{         
    static enumKey<T>(innerEnum:T,value:number):string{
        return innerEnum[value];
    }
}
var test = Util.enumKey(IFundingMethods,IFundingMethods.CREDIT_CARD);
alert(test);
```

hope this helps

Comment: the problem with this method is that the person using the library would need to use `Util.enumKey`... which kinda defeats the purpose of type safe of enums, but is an interesting workaround

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make it transform to ONLINE_DEBIT string without having to typecast it

If you want compile time safety you would need something that is `string` underneath (enums are `numbers` and all numbers are compatible with an enum).

There is a request for this here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1003 (also called `tagged unions` or `string unions`).